# Inconsistent superscript positioning

Tags: math-mode, subscripts, superscripts

Observe the following examples of combinations of subscripts and superscripts:

```
  $\varphi_n$ $\varphi_n^m$ $\varphi_n^{f(n)}$ $\varphi_n^f$ $\varphi_n^($
```

[image]

We can  see that if a superscript is added, the subscript is automatically lowered a bit. But for some reason, this doesn't happen with $\varphi_n^{f(n)}$. A quick exploration shows that the opening parenthesis is to blame.

Why doesn't the automatic lowering of the subscript work with a parenthesis? Is this a bug? How to fix it?

Comment: As always on the site please provide a full (but minimal) example that others can copy and test as is. This may depend on several factors

Comment: You get the expected output in display math mode. In inline math mode, the excessive height+depth of the parenthesis triggers a different rule (which is somewhat unexpected, I admit).

Comment: @daleif: I've added the code.

Comment: I think you meant `$\varphi_n^{f(n)}$`

Comment: @Electroelf Oh, sorry. I'm too used to type Unicode directly. :-)

Comment: It wasn't obvious at first that this was inline math. Egreg has already provided an explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want you can smash the parentheses so they don't count for positioning calculations:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
 $\varphi_n$ $\varphi_n^m$ $\varphi_n^{f\smash{(n)}}$ $\varphi_n^f$ $\varphi_n^{\smash{(}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

The red line was added in an image editor for illustration purposes.

Comment: +1. You may want to change `$\varphi_n$` to `$\varphi^{}_n$` in order to show how to lower the subscript material if there's no superscript material at all.